# Problem with Building Arrays in Different Coding Styles

Tags: php, arrays, loops, operators

I'm having a strange problem while building arrays.  I start off with an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
       [0] => Array (
                      [tag_id] => 19
                      [tag_translation_id] => 12
                      [fk_language_id] => 1
                      [fk_tag_id] => 19
                      [tag_name] => test
                    )
       [1] => Array (
                      [tag_id] => 20
                      [tag_translation_id] => 14
                      [fk_language_id] => 1
                      [fk_tag_id] => 20
                      [tag_name] => testa
                    )
       [2] => Array (
                      [tag_id] => 20
                      [tag_translation_id] => 15
                      [fk_language_id] => 3
                      [fk_tag_id] => 20
                      [tag_name] => fdfda
                    )
       )
```

What I want to do is merge each result with the same tag_id into a single array.  This works:

```
    $tags = array();
    foreach($results->as_array() as $key=>$result)
    {
        if(!in_array($result['tag_id'], $tags))
        {
            $tags[$result['tag_id']] = array();
        }   
    }

    foreach($results->as_array() as $result)
    {
        array_push($tags[$result['tag_id']], array($result['fk_language_id'] , $result['tag_name']));   
    }
```

Here is the intended result:

```
Array ( 
  [19] => Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
               [0] => 1 
               [1] => test 
           ) 
       ) 
  [20] => Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
               [0] => 1 
               [1] => testa 
           ) 
       [1] => Array (  
               [0] => 3 
               [1] => fdfda 
           ) 
       ) 
)
```

However, I've got two loops here, and I know this isn't ideal.  Why do THESE not work??

```
    $tags = array();
    foreach($results->as_array() as $key=>$result)
    {
        $tags[$result['tag_id']] .= array($result['fk_language_id'] , $result['tag_name']);
    }
```

With this example I get two empty arrays...

```
Array ( [19] => Array [20] => ArrayArray )
```

Or even...

```
    $tags = array();
    foreach($results->as_array() as $key=>$result)
    {
        if(!in_array($result['tag_id'], $tags))
        {
            $tags[$result['tag_id']] = array();
        }
        array_push($tags[$result['tag_id']], array($result['fk_language_id'] , $result['tag_name']));
    }
```

Which for some reason overwrites the first value of the second array with the second value of the second array.

```
Array ( 
  [19] => Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
               [0] => 1 
               [1] => test 
           ) 
       ) 
  [20] => Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
               [0] => 3 
               [1] => fdfda 
           ) 
       ) 
 )
```

What am I doing wrong in the second 2 examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, your second method fails because you're using the incorrect `.=` operator. Your third method fails because your `!in_array` check is always `false` (it checks whether the *value* is in the array, not whether the *key* is set) and overwrites the array each iteration. You only really need this (as mentioned by others, in pseudo-code):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $values) {
    $result[$values['key']][] = array($values['foo'], $values['bar']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.=` operator is string concatenation. Arrays are merged with `+=`.

If I understand the issue correctly, the code should go like this:

```
$tags = array();
foreach ($results as $result)
    $tags[$result['tag_id']][] = array($result['fk_language_id'], $result['tag_name']);
```

Comment: This is the rough equivalent of the last example, and will not work.  This also removes the last result.  Remember, I need to concatenate multiple results.  The += gives me unsupported operand types.

Comment: You don't need to CONCATENATE. Concatenation is joining two strings, not merging arrays. `+=` will give you unsupported operand types if you actually use wrong operands, ie, you're doing something wrong. Check my edited answer - it gives exactly the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tags = array();
foreach($results->as_array() as $key=>$result)
{
    $tags[$result['tag_id']] .= array($result['fk_language_id'] , $result['tag_name']);
}
```

you cannot add a value to an array with the .= (dot equal) operator.

why are you doing $results->as_array() ????

do simply:

```
foreach($results as $key=>$result) {
```

Comment: as_array seems to be a special method of whatever is in $results. You have no idea whether $results is Iterable or not.

Comment: Yea, it's an operation on an object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .= try using []

```
$tags = array();
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    if(!isset($tags[$result['tag_id']]))
        $tags[$result['tag_id']] = array();
    $tags[$result['tag_id']][] = array($result['fk_language_id'], result['tag_name']);
}
```

.= is to concatinate a string
+= is to concatinate a number
[] is to concatinate to an array

Hope this helps?

Edit: Noticed that it "might" fail if the tag_id doesn't already exist in the array, so it might be worth just checking first and setting it to an array just in case.

Comment: It won't fail if `tag_id` doesn't exist, you don't need to explicitly create a new array.